# Stream writer not writing all data into file

Tags: c#

I am kinda new with c#. I want my code to create a new text file and write everything from an array of strings into the file.

```
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(this.oof[i]);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
                sw.Dispose();

            }

        }
```

The .txt file is suppose to contain (first name, last name, phone number, address) but the actual outcome is only has first name, black space, blank space, address). Is this an issue of data loss?

Comment: There’s no point in using that finally block when you already wrap the code in the using statement. Have you checked your data that it actually contains what you think? StreamWriter will write what you give to it

Comment: Have you check to see what the array `oof` contains before you write it to a file? In addition, the loop stopping condition of 13 seems odd. I would think `oof.Length` would be a more appropriate stopping condition.

Comment: Use debugger, set break point in the `for` loop, look at what `this.oof[i]` contains, then you probably can find the answer to your question.